# wrapper with opacity and set div on this wrapper without opacity

Tags: html, css

I have wrapper div that has opacity set to 0.75. The problem is that when I place another div it also is transparent.

Here is **HTML**:

```
<div id="header_wrapper">
     <div id="header">
         <div class="logo"></div>               
         <ul class="hor_list" id="main_menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header_wrapper {           
    background: black;
    opacity:0.75;
    filter:alpha(opacity=75); /* For IE8 and earlier */         
    height: 82px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

In this case `div.logo` and `ul#main_menu` are both transparent and this is a problem. How to stop this?

Comment: Please show also the CSS. To which div you set the opactiy?

Comment: _“How to stop this?”_ – by _not_ placing them inside the element with opacity. Opacity works on an element _and all its content_, and there is no way to “reverse” it.

Comment: Use `RGBA`, [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hwz6u/).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent the child node from having the parent's opacity, two workarounds would be absolute positioning to place it whereever you need it without being direct child of the opacity parent, OR, most likely that you want the opacity for background, then you can use the RGBA color scheme:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75);
```

with 0.75 being the opacity value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an opacity u can use rgba as a backgroundcolor.

example:

```
#div {
   background: rbga(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a div is set opacity all the contents inside the div will have the opacity, there is no way to change this behavior than on simple thing.

Make wrapper div position relative, and header div position absolute and so that it will be solved. top and left are based on header div positions relative to wrapper div

```
<div id="header_wrapper" style="position:relative">
     <div id="header" style="postition:absolute; top:10px;left:10px">
         <div class="logo"></div>               
         <ul class="hor_list" id="main_menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

I hope it helped :)